# How do I set initial music volume to be 50% using UIslider iOs? I am using AVFoundation

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, uislider

I searched around stackoverflow but I couldn't find anything that helped.  I am currently building a simple music app.  My problem is that the slider that I am using to control the volume levels plays the song at full volume, or 100% of the volume when the app first runs.  What I want to do is to adjust this to be at only 50% of the volume so when I drag the slider to the right, I can increase the volume.  Currently, when I drag the slider to the right, the volume stays the same because like I mentioned before when I run the app, the volume is already at maximum level. However when I drag it to the left, the volume does decrease as expected which has me even more confused. I should also add the slider's value is set to be 0.5 at the time of creation as it should.  I will post the code below, please help.
I create the slider inside the configurePlayer() method, and I am trying to adjust the volume inside the last method

'''

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class playerViewController: UIViewController {
var position: Int = 0
var Gabay = [Gabays]()
var player: AVAudioPlayer?


var timer: Timer?



@IBOutlet var holder: UIView!
let forWardButton = UIButton()
let backwardsButton = UIButton()
let playPauseButton = UIButton()

//userinterfact elements
private let coverImageView: UIImageView = {
    
    let imageView=UIImageView()
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    return imageView
}()

private let trackNameLabel: UILabel = {
    let gabayNameLabel = UILabel()
    gabayNameLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica-bold", size: 20)
    return gabayNameLabel
}()

private let artist: UILabel = {
    let artistName = UILabel()
    artistName.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica-bold", size: 20)
    artistName.textAlignment = .left

    return artistName
}()


    




//MARK: - life cycle
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = .systemGreen
}

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    if holder.subviews.count == 0{
        configurePlayer()
    }
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    if let player = player{
        player.stop()
    }
}


// MARK: - Table view data source




//configure
func configurePlayer() {
    //set up player
    let gabay = Gabay[position]

    //loading the gabays from disc or array
    let urlString = Bundle.main.path(forResource: gabay.trackName, ofType: "mp3")
    
    do{
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setMode(.default)
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true, options: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)
        
        guard let urlString = urlString else{return}
        
        player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(string: urlString)!)
        guard let player = player else{return}
        //play the audio
        player.play()

        
    }
    
    catch{
        print("Error is: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
    
        //set up imageView cover
    coverImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 15, y: 10, width: holder.frame.size.width - 20, height: holder.frame.size.height - 350)
    coverImageView.image = UIImage(named: gabay.imageName)
    holder.addSubview(coverImageView)
    
    //set up labels
    trackNameLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 150, y: 15, width: holder.frame.size.width - 40, height: holder.frame.size.width + 470)
    trackNameLabel.text = gabay.trackName
    
    holder.addSubview(trackNameLabel)
    
    artist.frame = CGRect(x: 150, y: 15, width: holder.frame.size.width  - 40, height: holder.frame.size.width + 540)
    artist.text = gabay.artist
    holder.addSubview(artist)
    
    //setting up buttons
    playPauseButton.setTitle("", for: .normal)
    playPauseButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(playButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    playPauseButton.frame = CGRect(x: 155, y: 600, width: (holder.frame.size.width)/6, height: holder.frame.size.height - 690)
    playPauseButton.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "play.fill"), for: .normal)
    holder.addSubview(playPauseButton)
    
    backwardsButton.setTitle("", for: .normal)
    backwardsButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(backButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    backwardsButton.frame = CGRect(x: 15, y: 600, width: (holder.frame.size.width)/6, height: holder.frame.size.height - 690)
    backwardsButton.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "backward.fill"), for: .normal)
    holder.addSubview(backwardsButton)
    
    forWardButton.setTitle("", for: .normal)
    forWardButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(forwardButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    forWardButton.frame = CGRect(x: 285, y: 600, width: (holder.frame.size.width)/6, height: holder.frame.size.height - 690)
    forWardButton.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "forward.fill"), for: .normal)
    holder.addSubview(forWardButton)
    
    //set volume slider
    
    let volumeSlider = UISlider()
    volumeSlider.minimumValue = 0.0
    volumeSlider.maximumValue = 1.0
    volumeSlider.alpha = 0.4
    volumeSlider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(volumeSliderChanged), for: .valueChanged)
    volumeSlider.value = 0.1
    volumeSlider.frame = CGRect(x: 15, y: 560, width: holder.frame.size.width  - 40, height: (holder.frame.size.width)/8)
    volumeSlider.setThumbImage(UIImage(systemName: "volume.3")?.withTintColor(.systemGray, renderingMode: .alwaysOriginal).resizableImage(withCapInsets: UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right:0)), for: .normal)
    holder.addSubview(volumeSlider)

    
    //set fast forward slider
    
    let seekSlider = UISlider()
    
    seekSlider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(seekThrough), for: .valueChanged)
    seekSlider.minimumValue = 0.0
    seekSlider.maximumValue = 1.0
    seekSlider.frame = CGRect(x: 15, y: 700, width: holder.frame.size.width  - 40, height: (holder.frame.size.width)/8)
    seekSlider.setThumbImage(UIImage(systemName: "circle.fill")?.withTintColor(.clear, renderingMode: .alwaysOriginal).resizableImage(withCapInsets: UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right:0)), for: .normal)

    holder.addSubview(seekSlider)
    
 

}

@objc func playButtonTapped(){
    guard let player = player else{return}
    if player.isPlaying{
        playPauseButton.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "pause.fill"), for: .normal)
        player.stop()
    }else{
        playPauseButton.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "play.fill"), for: .normal)
        player.play()

    }
}

@objc func backButtonTapped(){
    if position > 0 {
        position = position - 1
        player?.stop()
        for subview in holder.subviews {
            subview.removeFromSuperview()
        }
        configurePlayer()
        
    }
}

@objc func forwardButtonTapped(){
   
    if position < Gabay.count - 1 {
       
        guard let player = player else{return}
        position = position + 1
        player.stop()
        for subview in holder.subviews {
            subview.removeFromSuperview()
        }
        configurePlayer()

    }
}






@objc func seekThrough(_ slider: UISlider){
    //get the duration of the current playing gabay
    var duration = player!.duration
    duration += 1
    //calculate
    let newPosition = Double(slider.value)*duration
    player!.currentTime = newPosition
    
    
    //make slider move along the song
 
}



@objc func volumeSliderChanged(_ slider: UISlider){
    let volumeValue = slider.value
    

    player!.volume = volumeValue
    
    //make the initial position of volume slider to be 50% of the volume
}
```

}

Comment: The volume is at 100% because that's what it defaults to and you only ever adjust the volume when the slider moves (in volumeSliderChanged). Set `player.volume = 0.5` immediately after initializing it to have it start at 50% like the UI slider.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I tried this, it did not work. I even tried to set the slider's initial value to be 1 so that it starts out at the end to match the volume being at 100%.  However, when I drag it to the left, the volume doesn't decrease until I pass halfway. same issue as before.

Answer (score 0):

The function `volumeSliderChanged()` is called every time the slider is used, which means any initialization added there will be repeatedly called every time someone uses the slider to  the volume.

Try adding `player!.volume = 0.5` right underneath `player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(string: urlString)!)` instead.

```
do{
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setMode(.default)
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true, options: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)
        
    guard let urlString = urlString else{return}
        
    player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(string: urlString)!)


    //Set up volume here 
    player!.volume = 0.5    


    guard let player = player else{return}
    //play the audio
    player.play()  
}
    
catch{
    print("Error is: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

Also try modifying the initial slider value from 0.1 to 0.5 in order for the slider position to match the starting volume.

```
let volumeSlider = UISlider()
volumeSlider.minimumValue = 0.0
volumeSlider.maximumValue = 1.0
volumeSlider.alpha = 0.4
volumeSlider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(volumeSliderChanged), for: .valueChanged)
//Set initial volume slider value to 0.5 (50%) to match the initial volume 
//volumeSlider.value = 0.1
volumeSlider.value = 0.5
```

As for the volume not decreasing, it might be because of [linear vs. logarithmic volume control](https://medium.com/zattoo_tech/logarithmic-volume-control-bd89cc1f2135). Here's the extension from the article (AVPlayer changed to AVAudioPlayer):

```
extension AVAudioPlayer {
    var logarithmicVolume: Float {
        get {
            return sqrt(volume)
        }
        set {
            volume = pow(newValue, 2)
        }
    }
}
```

Replacing every instance of `player!.volume` with `player!.logarithmicVolume` might help with the issue.